# Will Made In Abyss season two feature the same producer as OST?

Tags: made-in-abyss

With many people highly recommending (Crunchyroll Anime Award-winning) the anime soundtrack alongside the song 'Tomorrow' receiving over 4.2 million plays on YouTube, do we know if Kevin Penkin has been announced as the producer for season two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off this [tweet by Kevin Penkin himself](https://twitter.com/kevinpenkin/status/1027293456182521857) from the 8th of August, I would say yes.

> When you [@miabyss_anime](https://twitter.com/miabyss_anime) recording session becomes Accidental Renaissance Art.